# How to get duplicate values across any, potentially not all, lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I have a dataset along the lines of:

```
data.append(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'x', 'y', z'], ['a', 'x', 'e', 'f'], ['a'])
```

I've searched SO and found ways to return duplicates across all lists using `intersection_update()` (so, in this example, `'a'`), but I actually want to return duplicates from *any* lists, i.e.,:

`retVal = ['a', 'x']`

Since `'a'` and `'x'` are duplicated at least once among all lists. Is there a built-in for Python 2.7 that can do this?

Comment: I would pass the lists to a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and look for all keys with value >= 2

Comment: your append statement is off;..

Comment: *to return duplicates from any lists* - can you elaborate?

Comment: given `['a','b','a'],['x','y']` would you return `'a'`?

Comment: Put another way, I want to return all elements which aren't unique when compared with the elements of every other list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to determine the number of each item and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to pass the items from the sublists to the `Counter`.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

data=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'x', 'e', 'f'], ['a']]
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(data))
retVal = [k for k, count in c.items() if count >= 2]
print(retVal)
#['x', 'a']
```

Comment: This does precisely what I was looking for.